# Laravel transaction conflict

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, transactions

I've table **"groups"** columns (id , min_num , max_num , .....name, etc)
with one to many relation to **"users"** table columns ( id , num , group_id , ......name, etc)
and 4 other tables ..

I'm having register transaction that generate sequence unique number to the user .
when execute one by one request , every thing gonna fine ...
when execute 10 threads at the same time .. then conflicts appear !!

whats I think happened in one second is :

1. user A request register so system start transaction and added to 4 another tables and generate number (1) depending on min-max in group of user and max number exists in users table , not yet commit .
2. user B request register so system start transaction and added to 4 another tables and generate number (1) depending on min-max in group of user and max number exists in users table, not yet commit .
3. user A commit ( done , so num 1 is in the DB ).
4. user B commit ( **ERROR** , num 1 is not unique).

how can I avoid this problem ?

Comment: Have you set the column to `unique()` when creating the table?

Comment: yes sure I did ..